# USB recognized in docking station when booting Windows - but not when booting Debian

Tags: debian, usb, hardware

I have a USB mouse and keyboard plugged in a Dell notebook which is connected to an I-Tec docking station. The docking station is connected to two monitors. In addition, two external USB harddisks are plugged into the docking station as well.

If I am booting this setup with Windows 11, everything works as intended. However, when booted with Debian (without plugging or unplugging anything), the two external harddisks are not recognized while the two monitors still are recognized.

If I plug in the mouse or keyboard to the docking station, I have the same USB behavior (recognized with Windows, unrecognized with Debian with the monitors always working0

I cannot explain why that it is let alone what I can do to make this work as intended.

Kernel and Debian version are reported as follows

```
$ uname -r
6.1.0-18-amd64

$ lsb_release -d
No LSB modules are available.
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how I can query the model of the dock station.

Comment: Can you provide the model of the dock station, the version of Debian and the kernel and tell us exactly what works and what doesn't? (it's not clear if the monitors work in both cases). Note that some models need drivers for Debian/Ubuntu, you might want to check [here](https://i-tec.pro/de/produkt/u3hdmidvidock-3/).

Comment: Is that *only* USB or also Thunderbolt? Dell usually has UEFI settings about Thunderbolt security. Linux has to be configured accordingly if such security is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the link which contains a link to a zip file with instructions which I followed. Now, i cannot even boot the notebook anymore into Debian (plugged or unplugged). Is there a suggestion how I can revert the changes?